# Example for Deploying a Tensorflow Model via a RESTful API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Is there any example code for deploying a Tensorflow Model via a RESTful API? I see examples for a command line program and for a mobile app. Is there a framework for this or people just load the model and expose the predict method via a web framework (like Flask)to take input (say via JSON) and return the response? By framework I mean scaling for large number of predict requests. Of course since the models are immutable we can launch multiple instances of our prediction server and put it behind a load balancer (like HAProxy). My question is, are people using some framework for this or doing this from scratch, or, maybe this is already available in Tensorflow and I have not noticed it.

Comment: I found a simple Flask example, and put the answer in the bottom. Is this something you were looking for? Please let me know Otherwise, I'll delete the answer.

BTW, I haven't tested the performance with TensorFlow Serving, but the Flask version seems decent for me.

Answer (score 23):

https://github.com/sugyan/tensorflow-mnist shows a simple restAPI example by using Flask and loading pre-trained mode (restore).

```
@app.route('/api/mnist', methods=['POST'])
def mnist():
    input = ((255 - np.array(request.json, dtype=np.uint8)) / 255.0).reshape(1, 784)
    output1 = simple(input)
    output2 = convolutional(input)
    return jsonify(results=[output1, output2])
```

Also, see the online demo at https://tensorflow-mnist.herokuapp.com/. It seems the API is fast enough.

Answer (score 19):

[TensorFlow Serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving) is a high performance, open source serving system for machine learning models, designed for production environments and optimized for TensorFlow. The initial release contains examples built with [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/), but you can easily replace the front-end (denoted as "client" in the diagram below) with a RESTful API to suit your needs.

[image]

To get started quickly, check out the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple).