# Tensorflow CNN model - RESTful API

Tags: python, rest, machine-learning, tensorflow

I developed a Convolutional Neural Network algorithm in python, which classifies images (.jpg) with a specific label, by

1) defining a custom CNN model;

2) setting up an estimator, which locally saves the save_summary and save_checkpoint steps;

3) training the estimator with the estimator.train function.

Now, if I run the estimator.predict function, with a new image, it returns the predicted label.

How can I deploy this trained estimator as RESTful API so that I can call it from a WEB page or an application?

Comment: What did you try so far with RESTful? Please share what you already have.

Comment: See [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/), and the answers to the (off-topic) question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036689/example-for-deploying-a-tensorflow-model-via-a-restful-api

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know if you have used some known framework (Keras, Tensorflow, MXNet...), as most have some recommended ways to serve models over an API.

If you built your solution from scratch, you can "just" use any web framework to deliver your model predictions. To get you started, you may want to take a look to [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org).